# Print each line to file every microsecond

Tags: bash, awk, file-writing

I have a large file which is created using live data from some source. 
It is timestamped as below (till nano precision)

```
YYYYMMDD-HH:MM:SS.000000000 some data1
YYYYMMDD-HH:MM:SS.000000100 some data Error
YYYYMMDD-HH:MM:SS.000000200 some data2
```

Actual logfile

```
    20170524-09:15:00.859733997 RequestType:HI|OrderID:150|ErrorCode:100107
    20170524-09:15:00.860863250 RequestType:HELLO|OrderID:153|Tok:0
    20170524-09:15:00.861469371 RequestType:BYE|OrderID:153|Tok:1
    20170524-09:15:00.959733997 RequestType:HI|OrderID:158|ErrorCode:100107
```

How to read line by line from 1 file and write to another file (speed of write being ~micro second )

I need to simulate the live environment by reading the fully logged file and printing it to a different file (each line per micro second) so that I can simulate the live environment.

This file in live env is appended very fast (as can be seen from timestamps)

`**#Background info of the problem :**`(can be ignored, just writing because SO users may write why what are you doing and downvote it)::
I have been using a script to give me count of "minutely" Errors.
For example in the above log 9:15 will have 2 Errors and so on.

In live env I continuously tail (cant cat as file is going to be very large) on the file and run the below command

```
tail -f $logfile | stdbuf -oL awk '/ErrorCode:100107/{key=$2":"$3;a[key]++} !/ErrorCode:100107/{LK=$2":"$3; if (LK != key && key){print key,a[key];delete a;key=""};system("")}' FS='[-:]'
```

Today the script hanged for some reason, therefore i want to create a simulation.
If there is any bug in my code, please do comment. I just build `a` hash that stored errorcount for the minute, if minute has changed print the previous minute count.

Comment: what is the issue, what result does your code return?

Comment: restructured my question

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a potential problem with your script using an array `a[]` to keep track of the count of errors and only deleting it in a specific set of circumstances. It could be filling up with counts for almost every minute in the day. An array's completely unnecessary anyway though so that's just "at a glance", I'm not thinking about the logic too hard.

idk about the tailing part but to do what you say you want your awk script to do would be just:

```
$ awk -F'[-:]' '{curr=$2":"$3} curr!=prev{if(cnt) print prev, cnt; cnt=0; prev=curr} /ErrorCode:100107/{cnt++} END{if (cnt) print prev, cnt}' file
09:15 2
```

Add `fflush()` (or `system("")` if you're stuck with an older, non-POSIX awk) after the `print`s if needed.

Comment: I guess he also wanted *to read line by line from 1 file and write to another file* but that's one of the things I wanted the OP would have elaborated

Comment: Right, that's why I said `idk about the tailing part`.

Answer (score -2):

Just put the read in a loop with a sleep and send it to a new log file:

```
while read line; do
    echo $line
    sleep 0.001
done < logfile.log > newlogfile.log &
```